# Help in solving a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-(xy\cdot e^x \ln(y)+ye^y)}{xy\cdot e^y\ln(x) + xe^x}$$

This equation cannot be homogenized. I tried to separate the variables and find suitable differential coefficients but I could not do so. I can see some symmetry in the top and bottom functions. Factorizing out x & y from the equation, I obtain

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y(x\cdot e^x \ln(y)+e^y)}{x(y\cdot e^y\ln(x) + e^x)}$$

This gives us $f(x,y)$ in the numerator and $f(y,x)$ in the denominator. I am unsure if this helps to solve the equation and am unable to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maple says $$ \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) ^{{{\rm e}^{x}}}{x}^{{{\rm e}^{y
 \left( x \right) }}}-{\it \_C1}=0
$$

Comment: Maybe try the relation $\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{\partial f/\partial x}{\partial f/\partial y}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute:
$$ 
\begin{cases}w=\ln y \implies y=e^w \\
v=\ln x \implies x=e^v
\end{cases}
$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-y(x\cdot e^x \ln(y)+e^y)}{x(y\cdot e^y\ln(x) + e^x)}$$
$$\frac{dw}{dv} = \frac{-(e^v\cdot e^{e^v} w+e^{e^w})}{(e^w\cdot e^{e^w}v + e^{e^v})}$$
$${dw}({(e^w\cdot e^{e^w}v + e^{e^v})}) = ({-(e^v\cdot e^{e^v} w+e^{e^w})})dv$$
$$e^we^{e^w}v{dw} + e^{e^v}{dw} = -e^ve^{e^v}w dv-e^{e^w}dv$$
This differential I think is exact
$$e^we^{e^w}v{dw} + e^{e^v}{dw} = -e^ve^{e^v}w dv-e^{e^w}dv$$
$$v{de^{e^w}} + e^{e^v}{dw} +w de^{e^v}+e^{e^w}dv=0$$
$${dve^{e^w}} + dwe^{e^v}=0$$
Integration:
$${ve^{e^w}} + we^{e^v}=K$$
Finally substitute back $x$ and $y$
$${e^y\ln x} + e^{x}\ln y=K$$
Take the exponetial on both sides if you want Maple solution posted by  Dr. Sonnhard Graubner 
$$x^{e^y}y^{e^x}=C$$